# Terminate batch job Y to exit

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to get my head around how the termination of a batch file works.

As I know CTRL+C or CTRL+SHIFT+BREAK prompts the user with the message "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"

From my reading pressing 'N' will continue the batch to the next command. However, pressing 'Y' just closes the batch file and returns to an open command prompt window. How can I get the command prompt window to close entirely from pressing the 'Y' option?

Comment: My first thought was to start your batch file as `myfile.bat & exit`, which, in theory, should run your batch file, and then once it is done, run the `exit` command to close the command prompt window. But it doesn't seem to work if the batch file is terminated with Ctrl+C. I'll keep fiddling with it, and maybe this will give someone else an idea.

Comment: Suggest you trap the errorlevel   generated by the Y answer and if found, branch to closing the command prompt window. It's exit code 3221225786, aka 0xC000013A or STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT. as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444765/why-does-a-non-interactive-batch-script-think-ive-pressed-control-c